# How to do digest authentication with micronaut http client?

Tags: java, micronaut, micronaut-client

i need to call an api that is using the digest authentication mechanism.

How to do that with micronaut http client?

i did authentication application with basic authentication easily with this simple HttpClientFiler:

```
    public Publisher<? extends HttpResponse<?>> doFilter(MutableHttpRequest<?> request, ClientFilterChain chain) {
        return chain.proceed(request.basicAuth(configuration.getUsername(), configuration.getToken()));
    }
```

But i do not find any thing to do the same with digest authentication. any idea?